# js add 7 minutes until 10 hours (00:07, 00: 14, 00:21...)

Tags: javascript, youtube

In youtube you can add ads to your video every 7 minutes. I want add 7 minutes 142 times. And print it in

```
console.log();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// New date object, initialized to "zero"
var d = new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

// While the hours property of the Date object is less than 10
while (d.getHours() < 10) {
    // Get hours part and pad with a 0 if necessary
    var hoursString = d.getHours().toString();
    if (hoursString.length == 1) {
        hoursString = "0" + hoursString;
    }

    // Get minutes part and pad with a 0 if necessary
    var minutesString = d.getMinutes().toString();
    if (minutesString.length == 1) {
        minutesString = "0" + minutesString;
    }

    // Log the time
    console.log(hoursString + ':' + minutesString);

    // Add 7 minutes and let the Date object handle overflow to hours internally
    d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 7);
}
```

You can find more information about the Date object [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).

Comment: page says "Sun Dec 31 1899 10:02:00 GMT+"

Comment: I need to see every step and get "00:07, 00: 14, 00:21, 00:28 ... 09:55)